# Why am I getting " module 'cv2' has no attribute 'resize'"

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, resize

I am using the following line in my program

```
img = cv2.resize(img, dsize=(299, 299), interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
```

It is giving the following error

```
AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'resize'
```

The type of image `img` is  `<class 'imageio.core.util.Array'>`

I checked the official documentation of OpenCV and [it contains the attribute resize](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga47a974309e9102f5f08231edc7e7529d).

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The issue occurred due to the erroneous installation of OpenCV.

Although the system is behaving as OpenCV was properly installed. It wasn't installed properly.

Uninstalling and installing OpenCV again solved the issue.

```
pip uninstall opencv-python
```

and then

```
pip install opencv-python
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your cv2 import is not correct. In a Python console, try

```
import cv2
help(cv2.resize)
```

In case it does not show the description of the resize method, the import does not work properly. Your could also check `help(cv2)`which gives a long list of all methods and attributes contained in the module.

Are you working within a virtual environment that needs activation first?